# Symfony2 Twig Form Widget Array Access

Tags: forms, symfony, widget, twig

I have a form widget with several choices (many-to-many relationship)
in twig template I can iterate over the checkboxes:

```
  {% for choice in form.downloads %}
            {{ form_widget(choice) }} {{ form_label(choice) }}<br />
  {% endfor %}
```

I'd like to acces the choices directly (they should bi formatted end positioned differently)
I tried several syntaxes but the doesn't work

```
{{ form_widget(form.downloads.0) }} {{ form_label(form.downloads.0) }}<br />
{{ form_widget(form.downloads['0']) }} {{ form_label(form.downloads['0']) }}<br />
{{ form_widget(form.downloads[0]) }} {{ form_label(form.downloads[0]) }}<br />
```

Do I use the wrong array keys or is array access generally not possible?

Answer (score 2):

Array Access is possible when you're using Twig.
I guess the error you got when you're trying to access the first generated checkbox using

```
{{ form_widget(form.downloads.0) }} {{ form_label(form.downloads.0) }}<br />
```

is

```
Method "0" for object "Symfony\Component\Form\FormView" does not exist in ...
```

So, you've just to use the child name of your checkbox. You should have in your buildForm something like:

```
 $builder->add('childName', 'anyTypeYouWant', array())
```

But I guess you're using collection type to generate your checkboxes. In this specific case

```
{{ form_widget(form.downloads.0) }} {{ form_label(form.downloads.0) }}<br />
```

should work fine! I already used it to access specific collection fields without customized keys.

**You should** also use the twig debug extension to check your form.downloads

```
{% debug form.downloads %}
```

and if the debug doesn't work, you've to add in your "app/config/config.yml" file

```
services:
    debug.twig.extension:
        class: Twig_Extensions_Extension_Debug
        tags: [{ name: 'twig.extension' }]
```

Comment: I found out the keys start not with 0 but with 3 - pretty random, dont really have an explanation for this

Comment: Can you just update your question and put the code you're using to generate your Form. (your buildForm)

Comment: ok, figured out: the keys are not random they are my ids of downloads in database

Comment: Ok, so you used the Id(s) as keys for your checkboxes. But if you're using collection type, the Id is just considered as an attribute of your child element and the collection you bound is an array with element positions as keys (starting by 0 as a default behavior if not customized)